Minimal number of generators for a p-primary ideal in a (not necessarily local) Noetherian ring
I know Atiyah Macdonald has the following theorem for Noetherian local rings (Theorem 11.14): The dimension of a Noetherian local ring $A$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ equals the least number of generators of an $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal of $A$.
Can we translate this statement to arbitrary Noetherian rings? In other words, is it true that if $\mathfrak{p}\in \textrm{Spec}(A)$ with $\textrm{ht} (\mathfrak{p}) = d$, then there exists some ideal $(x_1,\ldots, x_d)$ with radical $\mathfrak{p}$?

It might help you to start by considering the simplest non-local case: where $A$ is Artinian but not local. In this case, each prime has height $0$, and it takes exactly one nonzero element to generate a prime ideal up to radical.
